# Pose does not work after appending

Tags: armature, append, pose-mode

**[image]**

I downloaded  a character and when I open it the bones work.
But after I append it to another project the pose seems not to go on. 
The skeleton is in pose position.
Did I append in a wrong way or what could be the solution?

The first picture is from the original character that I found on the blendswap. The bones work there.
The second picture is when I appended it in my project but why can´t I move any bone there?

[image]

Comment: Please give some more infos (screentshot of model with his modifiers, the rig, and so on ....) or upload your file to get examinated.

Comment: are these pictures inaf or do you need more info ?

Comment: From the first picure I can see that an FK forearm bone is selected, while in the N panel the FK/IK slider is set to IK, so the FK bone will not influence the character's arm. If this is not the problem, I think you should upload the file. Anyway, I don't think it's an appending issue: probably the appending procedure resets some not stored hidden controls (like the IK/FK one).

Comment: sorry to bother, but how do i upload in this section !

Comment: You can use this site and the write the adress in theese comments https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi i tryet to upload the file , did it go throw, if not can you give a more detailed instruction or share a link for a more detailed instruction of how to upload it, i managet to uplaod somethign but im not sure did i manage to it right .

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3865" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3865/)

Comment: You should upload the Elanie file also: as it's appended it's not saved with the scene file.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3880" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3880/)

Answer (score 1):

In object mode select the rig, press <kbd>L</kbd>
(make local) and choose "All".

[image]

Comment: That´s great, it worket , thank you very much .

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer clicking on the relative up arrow.